# string array to Int array using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, int

Below is the code I have so far and it isn't working as I want it to, so I need some help.

The string[] `FCVs` comes back with strings...each looking somewhat like this `$103,700</td><t` but with different numbers.

I want to have these numbers come back as an integer.

The function returns a List because of the very first item `Description` is a string.

```
public static List<object> processPage(string sourceCode)
{
    List<object> ItemsToReturn = new List<object>();
    string Description = getBetween(sourceCode, @"Description:</td><td style=""padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 8pt; vertical-align: top;"">", "</td>");                        
    ItemsToReturn.Add(Description);

    string FullCashValue = getBetween(sourceCode, @"Full Cash Value</a>", "<a href");
    string[] FCVs = new string[2];
    int index1 = FullCashValue.IndexOf("$");
    FCVs[0] = FullCashValue.Substring(index1, 15).ToString(); //2014
    int index2 = FullCashValue.IndexOf("$", index1 + 1);
    FCVs[1] = FullCashValue.Substring(index2, 15).ToString(); //2013

    int[] int_FCVs;
    for (int i = 0; i < FCVs.Count(); i++)
    {               
        Match m = Regex.Match(FCVs[I], @"[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([Ee][+-]?\d+)?");
        int_FCVs[i] = m.Value;               
    }

    foreach (int FCV in int_FCVs)
    {
        ItemsToReturn.Add(FCV);
    } 
}
```

Comment: and what are you asking ? what is the problem that you are having ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to just return an int it may be as simple as the following:

```
int outputValue;
int.TryParse(Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[\D]", ""), out outputValue);
```

This puts 103700 into the outputValue variable. You'll want to expand on it and add handling for items that don't have numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You might find scraping the various bits and pieces out of the HTML simpler if you loaded the HTML into an `HTMLDocument` per the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935634/467473) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935482/467473) to the question [String to HtmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935446/string-to-htmldocument-c-sharp). Or, if you know the HTML is valid XML (not a given!), you can just load it into an XmlDocument. In either event, you can then easily extract the various bits and pieces of the content you want using XPath selectors.

However, given text containing currency values like you have, I'd probably write a little helper method to extract the currency values from the text:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ParseCurrencyValuesFromString( this string s )
{
  for ( Match m = rxCurrencyValue.Match( s ) ; m.Success ; m.NextMatch() )
  {
    yield return m.Value ;
  }
}
private static Regex rxCurrencyValue = new Regex( @"\$\d\d?\d?(,\d\d\d)*(\.\d+)?");
```

The regular expression matches a literal `$` followed by a 1-3 digit group, followed by zero or more 3 digit groups separated by commas, followed by an optional fractional component. Examples:

- `$3`
- `$32`
- `$321`
- `$3.97`
- `$32,987.1234`
- etc.

Once you have that, it's a simple Linq incantation to get what you want...

```
string text      = "$1, $2.34, $123, $1,234, $12,345, $123,456, $12,345,678.9012" ;
int[]  intValues = text.ParseCurrencyValuesFromString()
                       .Select( v => decimal.Parse(v,NumberStyles.Currency))
                       .Select( d => (int) Math.Round(d,MidpointRounding.ToEven))
                       .ToArray()
                       ;
```

Let the regular expression engine do the work for you.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could examine the current culture and construct the regular expression on the fly using the defined currency symbol, thousands seperator and decimal points. The regular expression will need to get a little fancier if you're going to have negative numbers, especially if they are indicated accountancy-style by being enclosed in parenthesis, but not that much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was very close. Completed code below.

```
 public static List<object> processPage(string sourceCode)
{
            //create List<object> to return
            List<object> ItemsToReturn = new List<object>();
            string Description = getBetween(sourceCode, @"Description:</td><td style=""padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 8pt; vertical-align: top;"">", "</td>");
            //add description (string) to List<object>          
            ItemsToReturn.Add(Description);

            //pull section to sort through from sourcecode
            string FullCashValue = getBetween(sourceCode, @"Full Cash Value</a>", "<a href");
            string[] FCVs = new string[2];
            //find index of $ sign
            int index1 = FullCashValue.IndexOf("$");
            //find $ amount + some extra characters for wiggle room
            FCVs[0] = FullCashValue.Substring(index1, 15).ToString(); //2014
            int index2 = FullCashValue.IndexOf("$", index1 + 1);
            FCVs[1] = FullCashValue.Substring(index2, 15).ToString(); //2013

            int[] int_FCVs = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < FCVs.Count(); i++)
            {
                // replace all non-digits with ""
                var m = Regex.Replace(FCVs[i], @"[^.0-9]", "");
                //convert var m to Int & place into array of ints
                int_FCVs[i] = Convert.ToInt32(m);                
            }
            //put each int into ItemsToReturn (list<object>)
            foreach (int FCV in int_FCVs)
            {
                ItemsToReturn.Add(FCV);
            } 

       return ItemsToReturn;
}
```