# C# Convert HtmlString into HTMLDocument

Tags: c#, dom

I have the HTML file Template which i need to read into HTMLDocument Object to modify the HTML Body.

I am unable to Load the HTMLString content into the HTMLDocument. any point with sample C# code would very helpful.

Thanks in advance for all your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935446/string-to-htmldocument) will help you.
You can find two ways to solve your problem:

- with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- with the following code :

---

```
  HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
  IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;    

  doc2.write(fileText);
```