# Unable to cast object of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' to type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2'

Tags: c#

iam to Unable to cast object of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' to type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2'

```
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;
```

Comment: Seems like error is pretty self-descriptive. You cannot cast type A to type B, like you cannot cast boolean to date

Comment: in this way we can cast the system.windowsforms.document 
 to html IHTMLDocument2 
 
 IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowserDomDocument.Document.DomDocument;
 
 it is possible but i was to cast in HTML AgilityP ack also

Answer (score 0):

In order to cast type `A` to type `B`, one of following should be true

- Type `A` should be inherited from type `B`, or it should implement type `B` if it's an interface. Implicit conversion will work in this case
- Type `B` should be inherited from type `A` and variable which you are casting should hold an instance of type `B`.
- There should be [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) defined in either type which performs conversion

If none is true, then you'll get a runtime exception. For types `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` and `mshtml.IHTMLDocument2` both conditions are not satisfied.

**UPDATE:** Seems like you have a typo - instead of declaring `doc` variable as `HTMLDocument` you have declared it as `HtmlDocument`. C# is a case-sensitive language.

Further reading: [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Comment: u don't  know about the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

Comment: @chandu you are using it, and you mention it in the question

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029448/c-sharp-convert-htmlstring-into-htmldocument    in this link stack over flow team said that it was correct but it not working.

Comment: @chandu answer is the same

Answer (score -1):

It is because `HTMLDocument` does not implement `IHTMLDocument2` so there's no known path to perform the cast.

Comment: implementation is not necessary

Comment: In this case it is because there's no explicit operator defined to perform the conversion. If you cast from object1 to object2 there must be some sort of relation between those types like inheritance, implementation or an operator that tells how the conversion should work.