# Can't using HtmlDocument in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I create Console Application using Selenium to get the text from a table.

Tried with code:

```
IList<IWebElement> tableRows = browser.FindElementsByXPath("id('column2')/tbody/tr");
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(tableRows);
```

This error like:

> 'HtmlDocument' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

[I read this answer from question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935482/6112401)

Almost people in Stackoverflow can be using like:

`new HtmlDocument`.

Why I can't be using this. I tried with Winform Application, but I also can't using HtmlDocument.

And `HtmlDocument` seems only `LoadHmtl(String)`. But my code is `IList<IWebElement>`.

I don't know how to convert it to HTML string to add to `doc`.

Comment: Are you using HtmlAgility Pack correctly as they are using it for HtmlDocument class.

Comment: Try this : `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`

Comment: In pre-comment suggest using `HtmlAgilityPack`. So I think `HtmlDocument` in namespace `System.Windows.Web`.  I will try with `HtmlAgility Pack`.

Comment: Thanks. When to install this package. It's working. But in question, I have a problem like LoadHtml only accept string HTML. But I want to add rows: `IList<IWebElement> tableRows = browser.FindElementsByXPath("id('column2')/tbody/tr");` to this. Have any method to do this? Thanks

Comment: why not continue with selenium ???, for what reason you want to use agility pack ?

Comment: When I tried scan table about ~1000 rows, it throws exception like: `Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IWebElement table = browser.FindElement(By.Id("column2");
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(table.InnerHtml);
```

first off all you can get the table elements using selenium... , if you chose to use agility pack you need to send to `LoadHtml` method **string** variable with html source so what you need to do is to find the html block (in your case is the table) take it as IWebElement and send it to LoadHtml using `table.InnerHtml`

also you can send the full page source `doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);`

Comment: Maybe provide some kind of explanation, not only code :) It's always helpful to learn and not only get the raw answer.

Comment: Thanks @leon barkan