# How to pass HTML code to a controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem, i work with MVC and i am trying to save HTML code of view in a DB field. I have on JS side of my MVC Solution the following code:

```
        var data = { id_perizia: $("#id_perizia").val(), pinSessione: $("#pin_sessione").val(), saveRegistration: flgSave, markup: document.documentElement.innerHTML }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: WebPerizie.baseUrl + "Registra/stopRecording",
        data: data,
        success: function (resp) {                  
            window.location.href = WebPerizie.baseUrl + "PT_PERIZIE/Edit/" + $("#id_perizia").val();
        },
        failure: function () {
            //console.log("Failed:::" + resp);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //console.log("Status code Error==="+e.status);
        },
    });
```

and my controller function parameter is:

```
public ActionResult stopRecording(decimal id_perizia, string pinSessione, bool saveRegistration, byte[] markup)
```

from the debugger i enter in the Controller, but i don't understand because the markup variable is always null. When i use in the browser console the command:

```
$("html").html();
```

or

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

i always get the HTML code of the page in the markup variable, but in the controller i have null. I have the sensation i wrong to pass the variable markup to the controller and the markup variable has the right value in the JS code. What do you think about it? What do i wrong? Can i get the HTML View code directly from the controller? If i can, is it a better solution?

Comment: WHY are you using ajax if you are redirecting after it?

Comment: really do we need to use byte for html ?

Comment: and WHY are you sending the page in the ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibility.
 
 
First of all check you are getting html or not in `alert()` and use string for html in your C# code (Remove byte). And also use validation false

Like below code

```
[ValidateInput(false)] 
public ActionResult stopRecording(decimal id_perizia, string pinSessione, bool saveRegistration, string markup)
```

Hope this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

You should use Html **Form** tag 
and pass like this

```
var data= $( "form" ).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: WebPerizie.baseUrl + "Registra/stopRecording",
        data: data,
        success: function (resp) {                  
            window.location.href = WebPerizie.baseUrl + "PT_PERIZIE/Edit/" + $("#id_perizia").val();
        },
        failure: function () {
            //console.log("Failed:::" + resp);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //console.log("Status code Error==="+e.status);
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string variable to controller and convert string to HtmlObject on controller side. this is better option.

1. JS side:

   ```
           var HtmlCode = '<div></div>'

           var dataArgs = '{' +
              '"code": "' + HtmlCode +
              '"}';

           var request = $.ajax({

               url: '@Url.Action("MethodName", "controllerName")',
               type: "POST",
               headers: headers,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: dataArgs,  
               dataType: "json"
           });

           request.done(function (msg) {

               //success
           });

           request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
               alert('Error submitting request.');
           });
   ```
2. c# side : string to HtmlDocument.
   [String to HtmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935446/string-to-htmldocument)