# Format HTML with C#

Tags: c#, html, format

I want to format html code with C#.
From this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body><h1>Hi, HTML!</h1></body></html>
```

I want this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi, HTML!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried:
`string result = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(source).ToString();`
And this works, but if I try this with Google website code, it throws some exceptions because
`doctype`isn't written correctly.

How can I format HTML code without HTML syntax error check?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Html is not XML, it just happens to look like it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String to HtmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935446/string-to-htmldocument)

Comment: Start here: https://html-agility-pack.net/